# How to get pod names from deployment?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

We have created deployments which in turns creates pod.
I need to get the Pod names created by my deployment file.

```
kubectl get -f deployment.yml
```

The above command list the deployment names. If i type `kubectl get pod` it displays the pod names which is having some random extra strings added with deployment names.

Even if i use the `-o json` option still unable to get the pod names.

How to get all the pods created by deployment? Even a shell script way would be fine.

my deployment file looks below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    ansible: test-2020-05-26-00-04-1590476651
    podRef: pod-ansibles
  name: rd-2020-05-26-00-04-1590476651
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        ...
        ....
```

so is there any way that i can get all pods which has deployment label 'test-2020-05-26-00-04-1590476651' ?

when i tried `'kubectl get pod -l ansible=test-2020-05-26-00-04-1590476651'` . it shows

`'No resources found in default namespace.'` seems it can only display deploy name `'kubectl get deploy -l ansible=test-2020-05-26-00-04-1590476651'`

But i need all pod names which is under a deployment..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, we label deployment's pods.

```
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
```

So, we can get all pod filter by label

```
kubectl get pod -l app=my-app
```

Answer (score 2):

All pods created by Kubernetes controller have its top owner's name in Pods' name. For pods created by a ReplicaSet, created by a Deployment it would look like:

```
PodName = ReplicaSetName-PodHash
```

ReplicaSet name in turn obey the same rule:

```
ReplicaSetName = DeploymentName-ReplicaSetHash
```

"Unfolded" Pod's name would look like:

```
PodName = DeploymentName-ReplicaSetHash-PodHash
```

Kubernetes requires that all resources of the same kind in the same namespace have different names.

So, to get the pods created by your deployment using kubectl we could use `grep` and `awk` to get just names:

```
kubectl get pods -n NamespaceName | grep "DeploymentName" | awk '{print $1}'
```

For ex:

```
kubectl get pods -n default | grep "rd-2020-05-26-00-04-1590476651" | awk '{print $1}'

# or just awk

kubectl get pods -n default | awk '/rd-2020-05-26-00-04-1590476651/{print $1}'
```